# navbar spacing is making collapsed size look silly

Tags: css, navbar

I have a navbar that looks pretty good apart from when its collapsed, the spacing between the options is too big. I like the height of the navbar and want to keep it the same but if I change the padding it makes the height too small in mormal viewing mode, grated the spacing between options is better but the overall look is not what I want. Also the image does not resize properly when viewing in mobile format? But I think this is due to the spacing again. Any help is appreciated.

```css
a[href^=tel] {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-default {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #00a3fe;
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-weight: 400;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-nav li a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  background-color: #49bdfe;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar-toggle,
.icon-bar {
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: white;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  color: : white;
  border: none;
  background: transparent !important;
}

.navbar-toggle:hover {
  background: transparent !important;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  border: none;
  background: transparent !important;
}

.navbar-toggle:hover {
  background: transparent !important;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  width: 22px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.navbar-toggle .top-bar {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 10% 10%;
}

.navbar-toggle .middle-bar {
  opacity: 0;
}

.navbar-toggle .bottom-bar {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 10% 90%;
}

.navbar-toggle.collapsed .top-bar {
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.navbar-toggle.collapsed .middle-bar {
  opacity: 1;
}

.navbar-toggle.collapsed .bottom-bar {
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font: 30px cursive;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0px;
}

.navbar-brand>img {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  width: auto;
}


/* EXAMPLE 3
    
    line height is 20px by default so add 30px top and bottom to equal the new .navbar-brand 80px height  */

.example3 .navbar-brand {
  height: 80px;
}

.example3 .nav>li>a {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.example3 .navbar-toggle {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 25px 15px 25px 0;
}

.navspacing {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.example3 {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!-- NAVBAR -->
<nav class='navbar navbar-default example3'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='navbar-header'>
      <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle collapsed' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#example-navbar-collapse'>
    <span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class='icon-bar top-bar'></span>
    <span class='icon-bar middle-bar'></span>
    <span class='icon-bar bottom-bar'></span></button>
      <span class='navbar-brand'><img src="images/f2p7.png" alt="faces2places" class="img-responsive" /></span></div>
    <div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='example-navbar-collapse'>
      <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
        <li><a href='about.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp' role='button'>About</a></li>
        <li><a href='get_bids.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp' role='button'>Get bids</a></li>
        <li><a href='register.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp' role='button'>Register company</a></li>
        <li><a href='contact.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp' role='button'>Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
        <li><a href='login.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp' role='button'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- NAVBAR -->
```

Comment: provide a working example please

Comment: No one will help you here if you will provide not-working code. Don't be lazy. Come on jules. You are better than that. Give us working fiddle to work with.

Comment: Not being lazy mate, Ive just up exactly the code i am using. So you want a fiddle, no problems mate

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this css

```
.example3 .nav >li >a {
     padding-top: 30px;
     padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

You should use

```
.example3 .nav >li >a {
     padding-top: 2.1 vw;
     padding-bottom: 2.1vw;
}
```

Comment: That sorts the problem of the spacing when collapsed but then the buttons dont fit fully and the text on the buttons is placed at the top? Thanks for your help

Comment: Jules it will be adjust according to the screen sizes as I already used in VW (viewport)...

Answer (score 1):

Please replace your css with the given css code.

```html
<style>
        a[href^=tel] {
          color: inherit;
          text-decoration: none;
        }

        .navbar-default {
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          padding-left: 10px;
          padding-right: 10px;
          border: 0;
          -webkit-border-radius: 0;
          -moz-border-radius: 0;
          border-radius: 0;
          background-color: #00a3fe;
          font-size: 14pt;
          font-weight: 400;
        }

        a:hover {
          text-decoration: none;
        }

        .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {
          color: #ffffff;
        }

        .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-nav li a {
          color: #ffffff;
        }

        .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
        .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
          background-color: #49bdfe;
          color: #FFFFFF;
        }

        .navbar-toggle,
        .icon-bar {
          border: 1px solid white;
          background-color: white;
        }

        .navbar-toggle {
          color: : white;
          border: none;
          background: transparent !important;
        }

        .navbar-toggle:hover {
          background: transparent !important;
        }

        .navbar-toggle {
          border: none;
          background: transparent !important;
        }

        .navbar-toggle:hover {
          background: transparent !important;
        }

        .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
          width: 22px;
          transition: all 0.2s;
        }

        .navbar-toggle .top-bar {
          transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform-origin: 10% 10%;
        }

        .navbar-toggle .middle-bar {
          opacity: 0;
        }

        .navbar-toggle .bottom-bar {
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
          transform-origin: 10% 90%;
        }

        .navbar-toggle.collapsed .top-bar {
          transform: rotate(0);
        }

        .navbar-toggle.collapsed .middle-bar {
          opacity: 1;
        }

        .navbar-toggle.collapsed .bottom-bar {
          transform: rotate(0);
        }

        .btn {
          display: inline-block;
          padding: 6px 12px;
          margin-bottom: 0;
          font-size: 14px;
          font-weight: normal;
          line-height: 1.42857143;
          text-align: center;
          white-space: nowrap;
          vertical-align: middle;
          cursor: pointer;
          -webkit-user-select: none;
          -moz-user-select: none;
          -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
          background-image: none;
          border: 1px solid transparent;
          border-radius: 4px;
          padding: 10px 16px;
          transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
        }

        .navbar-brand {
          font: 30px cursive;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
        }

        .navbar-brand {
          padding: 0px;
        }

        .navbar-brand>img {
          height: 100%;
          padding: 15px;
          width: auto;
        }
        ul.nav.navbar-nav {
        margin: 0;
        -webkit-margin-before: 0 !important;
        -webkit-margin-after: 0 !important;
    }

        /* EXAMPLE 3
            
            line height is 20px by default so add 30px top and bottom to equal the new .navbar-brand 80px height  */

        .example3 .navbar-brand {
          height: 80px;
        }

        .example3 .nav>li>a {
          padding-top: 5px;
          padding-bottom: 5px;
        }

        .example3 .navbar-toggle {
          padding: 10px;
          margin: 25px 15px 25px 0;
        }

        .navspacing {
          padding-left: 30px;
          padding-right: 30px;
        }

        .example3 {
          padding-left: 30px;
          padding-right: 30px;
        }
    </style>
```

```
<nav class='navbar navbar-default example3'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='navbar-header'>
      <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle collapsed' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#example-navbar-collapse'>
    <span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class='icon-bar top-bar'></span>
    <span class='icon-bar middle-bar'></span>
    <span class='icon-bar bottom-bar'></span></button>
      <span class='navbar-brand'><img src="images/f2p7.png" alt="faces2places" class="img-responsive" /></span></div>
    <div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='example-navbar-collapse'>
      <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
        <li><a href='about.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp' role='button'>About</a></li>
        <li><a href='get_bids.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp' role='button'>Get bids</a></li>
        <li><a href='register.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp' role='button'>Register company</a></li>
        <li><a href='contact.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp' role='button'>Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
        <li><a href='login.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp' role='button'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this and use `media query` for reponsive mode**

```css
a[href^=tel] {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-default {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #00a3fe;
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-weight: 400;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-nav li a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  background-color: #49bdfe;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar-toggle,
.icon-bar {
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: white;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  color: : white;
  border: none;
  background: transparent !important;
}

.navbar-toggle:hover {
  background: transparent !important;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  border: none;
  background: transparent !important;
}

.navbar-toggle:hover {
  background: transparent !important;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  width: 22px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.navbar-toggle .top-bar {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 10% 10%;
}

.navbar-toggle .middle-bar {
  opacity: 0;
}

.navbar-toggle .bottom-bar {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 10% 90%;
}

.navbar-toggle.collapsed .top-bar {
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.navbar-toggle.collapsed .middle-bar {
  opacity: 1;
}

.navbar-toggle.collapsed .bottom-bar {
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font: 30px cursive;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0px;
}

.navbar-brand>img {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  width: auto;
}


/* EXAMPLE 3
    
    line height is 20px by default so add 30px top and bottom to equal the new .navbar-brand 80px height  */

.example3 .navbar-brand {
  height: auto;
}

.example3 .nav>li>a {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.example3 .navbar-toggle {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 15px 15px 0px 0;
}

.navspacing {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.example3 {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!-- NAVBAR -->
<nav class='navbar navbar-default example3'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='navbar-header'>
      <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle collapsed' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#example-navbar-collapse'>
    <span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class='icon-bar top-bar'></span>
    <span class='icon-bar middle-bar'></span>
    <span class='icon-bar bottom-bar'></span></button>
      <span class='navbar-brand'><img src="images/f2p7.png" alt="faces2places" class="img-responsive" /></span></div>
    <div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='example-navbar-collapse'>
      <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
        <li><a href='about.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp' role='button'>About</a></li>
        <li><a href='get_bids.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp' role='button'>Get bids</a></li>
        <li><a href='register.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp' role='button'>Register company</a></li>
        <li><a href='contact.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp' role='button'>Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
        <li><a href='login.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp' role='button'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- NAVBAR -->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    a[href^=tel] {
      color: inherit;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .navbar-default {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-right: 10px;
      border: 0;
      -webkit-border-radius: 0;
      -moz-border-radius: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
      background-color: #00a3fe;
      font-size: 14pt;
      font-weight: 400;
    }

    a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {
      color: #ffffff;
    }

    .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-nav li a {
      color: #ffffff;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
      background-color: #49bdfe;
      color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    .navbar-toggle,
    .icon-bar {
      border: 1px solid white;
      background-color: white;
    }

    .navbar-toggle {
      color: : white;
      border: none;
      background: transparent !important;
    }

    .navbar-toggle:hover {
      background: transparent !important;
    }

    .navbar-toggle {
      border: none;
      background: transparent !important;
    }

    .navbar-toggle:hover {
      background: transparent !important;
    }

    .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
      width: 22px;
      transition: all 0.2s;
    }

    .navbar-toggle .top-bar {
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      transform-origin: 10% 10%;
    }

    .navbar-toggle .middle-bar {
      opacity: 0;
    }

    .navbar-toggle .bottom-bar {
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
      transform-origin: 10% 90%;
    }

    .navbar-toggle.collapsed .top-bar {
      transform: rotate(0);
    }

    .navbar-toggle.collapsed .middle-bar {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .navbar-toggle.collapsed .bottom-bar {
      transform: rotate(0);
    }

    .btn {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 6px 12px;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: normal;
      line-height: 1.42857143;
      text-align: center;
      white-space: nowrap;
      vertical-align: middle;
      cursor: pointer;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
      background-image: none;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      border-radius: 4px;
      padding: 10px 16px;
      transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    }

    .navbar-brand {
      font: 30px cursive;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .navbar-brand {
      padding: 0px;
    }

    .navbar-brand>img {
      height: 100%;
      padding: 15px;
      width: auto;
    }


    /* EXAMPLE 3
        
        line height is 20px by default so add 30px top and bottom to equal the new .navbar-brand 80px height  */

    .example3 .navbar-brand {
      height: 80px;
    }

    .example3 .nav>li>a {
      padding-top: 2.1vw;
      padding-bottom: 2.1vw;
    }

    .example3 .navbar-toggle {
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 25px 15px 25px 0;
    }

    .navspacing {
      padding-left: 30px;
      padding-right: 30px;
    }

    .example3 {
      padding-left: 30px;
      padding-right: 30px;
    }
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- NAVBAR -->
    <nav class='navbar navbar-default example3'>
      <div class='container'>
        <div class='navbar-header'>
          <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle collapsed' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#example-navbar-collapse'>
        <span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class='icon-bar top-bar'></span>
        <span class='icon-bar middle-bar'></span>
        <span class='icon-bar bottom-bar'></span></button>
          <span class='navbar-brand'><img src="images/f2p7.png" alt="faces2places" class="img-responsive" /></span></div>
        <div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='example-navbar-collapse'>
          <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
            <li><a href='about.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp' role='button'>About</a></li>
            <li><a href='get_bids.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp' role='button'>Get bids</a></li>
            <li><a href='register.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp' role='button'>Register company</a></li>
            <li><a href='contact.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp' role='button'>Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
            <li><a href='login.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp' role='button'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span> Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- NAVBAR -->
```